# Filling an array with letters A to (User selected value)

Tags: arrays, loops, delphi

What I have is a for loop from 1 to a random number under 10. The loop is filling an array with letters so say the random number was 6:
The array would be A,B,C,D,E,F except I haven't found a way to increase a character value each time the loop runs.

Code so far:

```
Random := RandomRange(2, 10);
  for I := 1 to Random do
  begin
    Piles[I] := 'A' + I - 1;   {Piles is an array of undefined size}
    Writeln (Piles[i]);
  end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just add to a `Char`. You'll have to do something like:

```
var
  Piles: string;
  C: Char;
  I: Integer;
  Count: Integer;
begin

  // ...

  Piles := '';
  Count := RandomRange(2, 10);
  for I := 1 to Count do
  begin
    C := Chr(Ord('A') + I - 1); 
    Piles := Piles + C;
    Writeln(C);
  end;
  Writeln;
  Writeln(Piles);

  // etc...
```

`Ord()` returns an `Integer` (with the ordinal value of the `Char`, in this case). You can add to an `Integer`. Then you turn it back into a `Char` with `Chr()`.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the fast answer however when I run it the code crashes. Piles is an array of string. Could this make a difference?

Comment: The code is breaking on: character := Chr(Ord('A') + I - 1); do I need to add something to uses?

Comment: What d you mean "breaking on"? Runtime or compile time error? if so, what is the exact error. Inexact information makes it impossible to help. Anyway, I just ran my code and it works fine. Did you perhaps just modify your code? Please do exactly what I did.

Comment: @Geeekoid: yes, you can't just add to dynamic array without using SetLength to allocate space for it. Of course that crashes.

Comment: Just realized that my array was undefined so it didn't work all sorted now! Thank you for the answer! +1

Comment: `System.Random` is a function, so a variable named `Random` isn't a great idea. Better to name that variable `Count`, or similar.

Comment: Changed `Random` into `Count`.

Comment: Additional point, is there a way to convert the letters to numbers with A being 0 or 1?

Comment: Use `Chr(Ord('0') + I -1)` for digits. But note that you can't have digits beyond '9'. <g>

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can "add" to `Char` using `Inc()` ( and subtract with `Dec()` );

```
c := 'A'; //c is a char variable
Random := RandomRange(2, 10);
for i := 1 to Random do
begin
  Piles[i] := c;
  Inc(c);
  Writeln(Piles[i]);
end;
```

Also you can loop on `Char` variable so

```
Random := RandomRange(2, 10);
for c := 'A' to Chr(Ord('A') + Random) do
begin
  Piles[i] := c;
  ShowMessage(Piles[i]);
end;
```

Finally you can also use `Succ()` and `Pred()` so another solution (assuming Piles is an array of `Char`) can be

```
Random := RandomRange(2, 10);
for i := 1 to Random do
begin
  if i = 1
    then Piles[i] := 'A'
    else Piles[i] := Succ(Piles[i-1]);
  ShowMessage(Piles[i]);
end;
```

**EDIT:**

**I often forget that `Inc()` and `Dec()` has a second parameter:**

```
var
  c: char;
begin
  c := 'A';
  Inc(c, 3);
  ShowMessage(c); //Shows D
end;
```

This way you can effectively add/subtract what you want to/from a `Char`